# How to set @ManagedProperty in CDI

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean

recently I was migrating JSF managed beans to CDI managed beans, but now I need to set a property from one bean to another in CDI, I mean how to adapt the annotation @ManagedProperty(value="#{articleBean.cverev}") using CDI. A fragment of my code is:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{

@Inject @Named
private ArticleBean articleBean;

/*In this part*/
@ManagedProperty(value="#{articleBean.cverev}")
private long cverev;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You already inject articlebean... the property is superfluous then

Comment: What is your JSF Version? 
There is no Managed Property in CDI its self, but with JSF 2.3 you can use javax.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty annotation for that.